# PostgreSQL missing /etc/postgresql folder?

Tags: 10.10, installation

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 10.10 (amd64).
Even though the Postgresql (8.4.5) server and client are installed, the postgresql directory in /etc folder is missing.

Any clues what could be cause of this problem.

Comment: Well, works for me anyway - http://paste.ubuntu.com/509394/. Did apt give you any errors while installing the package postgresql-8.4?

Comment: For me the postgresql directory exists in /etc but then it ends. Usually there should be a folder with the version number in it....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was to reinstall after purging the packages.

`sudo apt-get remove --purge postgresql-8.4`

then

`sudo apt-get install postgresql-8.4`

Comment: Same idea worked for me on Ubuntu 18.10 with `postgresql-11`.

Comment: Did't solve it for me... sadly... But for me "only" the dirs inside the postgresql dir are missing. Should be /etc/postgresql/10/main/